# PL/SQL functions

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Homework on PL/SQL FUNCTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521906/homework-on-pl-sql-functions)
>   [plsql functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524625/plsql-functions)

Function:

1. function to `Display_Employee_Name_In_Uppercase` that accepts the `Employee_ID` from the `Empoyees` table and returns the first and the last name of the employee in uppercase.
2. Write a small PL/SQL program to display the names of the employees whose  `Employee_IDs` are 107, 200 and 205.

this is what I have done I didnt know how to complete it 
can help ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION disp (emp_id in  varchar20) return emp_name
select into emp_name 
fname||lname 
from employees 
where employee_id=emp_id
END disp ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION Fn_Display(p_empId IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2

IS

empName VARCHAR2(100);    

BEGIN

 BEGIN
  SELECT UPPER(first_name || ' ' || last_name)
  INTO  empName
  FROM Employees
  WHERE employee_id = p_empId; 
 EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND                
 END;


 RETURN empName;

END Fn_Display;
```

You can call this function wherever you want. here is a sample...

```
  DECLARE

    empId VARCHAR2(100);
    empName VARCHAR2(100);

  BEGIN

    empId := &ENTER_EMPLOYEE_ID;
    empName := Fn_Display(empId);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Name: '||empName);

  END;
```

Comment: Your error handling is poor.  It's worse than having no exception handler at all.  The function should *raise exceptions*.  Otherwise any failure is suppressed.  If the client application doesn't support DBMS_OUTPUT or if it is disabled the user will get no feedback in the event of an error occuring.

Comment: @APC Thanks a lot. Being just a beginner in PL/SQL, I really appreciate your comments. I have edited the code to remove the faults you indicated.

Comment: Better to name your parameter as employee_id, the same as the column name, and then qualify the reference to it in the query with the function name. eg. "WHERE employee_id = fn_display.employee_id"

Comment: This is still not a good exception handling. You catch the exception and then raise it again. It might make sense to return a string saying the emp does not exists or raising a meaningful exception i.e: `raise-application_error(-20001,'The emp does not exists in DB')

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code, maybe this one works for you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION disp (emp_id in  varchar2) return varchar2 IS
emp_name varchar2(256);
BEGIN
  select UPPER(fname || ' ' || lname) 
  into emp_name  
  from employees 
  where employee_id = emp_id;
  return emp_name;
END disp;
```